# Django | Al hacer pull desde server me devuelve conflicto con archivos .PYC

Tags: django, ubuntu, git

Cuando hago git pull desde server, me devuelve un error diciendo que hay coflicto con los archivos .pyc. Entonces en local pongo en ignore los archivos *.pyc Hago push (local a repositorio github). Después desde server hago pull de nuevo, pero me devuelve el mismo error. ¿Qué sucede?
¿Será que los archivos .pyc ya están en el repositorio y aunque ignore ya no consigo nada?
¿Cómo puedo solucionar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas probable es que ya estén el repositorio y ya estén siendo rastreados por git, como mencionas ya lo agregaste al ignore y por lo que comento anteriormente no le va a hacer caso para ignorar los archivos. Como dice en esta linea:

"Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge"

Te sugiere que hagas un stash, lo primero que tienes que hacer es:

```
git stash
```

Lo cual va a almacenar temporalmente esos archivos(o cambios hechos). Posteriormente harás tu pull

```
git pull origin mibranch
```

Esto ya debería de descargarte tus cambios, y por ultimo haces para regresar lo que almacenaste con stash

```
git stash pop
```

Como recomendación general en tu gitignore siempre agrega los archivos pyc ya que no es necesario subirlos. Ahora para que acepte tu gitignore con los cambios necesitas hacer los siguiente:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Esta instrucción ejecuta un comando recursivo para limpiar tu repositorio y dejar de rastrear todos los archivos.

```
git add .
```

Vas a volver a agregar todos tus archivos con git add .

Y por ultimo haces el commit:

```
git commit -m ".fix gitignore"
```

Con esto ya no deberías de tener los archivos pyc en tu repositorio pero si todo lo demás.

Espero esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.